# Command Line input to PHP Array

Tags: php, regex, string

I have this file *code.php* which works as interactive application on command line. The part of code goes like this

```
$f = fopen('php://stdin','w');
$input = fgets($f);
```

Now i want to convert this input string into an array of arguments. I am delimiting the argument on **Space Character**. for example :

```
$arguments = explode(' ', $input);
```

It works fine for most of the cases, but i want to insert one more case where string has *space* in itself. for example :

```
$input // "a var" and a 123
```

This code should break into an array of four elements not five. I believe its possible with regular expression. But is there any other much simpler and faster option for this in PHP.

If not, please help with most optimised **regular expression**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be easily done with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
<?php

$string = 'argument1 argument2 "argument3 with spaces" argument4';
$regex = '~"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\ ~';

$arguments = preg_split($regex, $string);
print_r($arguments);
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/jvgFJ5) and [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/tE9aL6/1), additionally.

---

The clue is to match everything between double quotes and then force the engine to throw the match away. The alternation after the `|` is then matched successfully. Obviously, this can be extended for single quotes and curly braces as well.

---

To even allow **escaped quotes**, you can adjust the expression with lookarounds:

```
(?<!\\)".*?(?<!\\)"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\
```

In `PHP`, you need to escape these as well, so the code becomes:

```
<?php

$string = 'argument1 argument2 "argument3 with spaces" argument4 "argument5 with \"escaped quotes\""';
$regex = '~(?<!\\\\)".*?(?<!\\\\)"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\ ~';

$arguments = preg_split($regex, $string);
print_r($arguments);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, it works with my problem. Can i escape quote with **\"**

Comment: @anwerjunaid: Please post all your requirements :) The expression can be adjusted to work with escaped quotes as well. See the updated answer.